# How to view per-app cellular data usage in iOS 10?

Tags: ios

In iOS 9, under settings -> Cellular, I can see how much cellular data each and every app has used.

But in iOS 10, it's no longer there. Has it been moved to somewhere else? Or removed at all from iOS 10?

Here is a screenshot of iOS 10. I've scrolled to the very bottom.

[image: ios10]

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, should still work as before (screenshot from iOS10):

[image]

Comment: Mine's the same as before, too - might be another carrier-related setting. O2 UK here.

Answer (score 1):

Found it.    Settings > cellular > apps using WLAN & Cellular.
There were no numbers in there before(probably because I hit reset) so I missed it...

[image]

Comment: Interesting. Wonder based on what it shows this additional menu item.